# Graphic ideas: crumbled paper effect

Tags: design, graphics

I'm thinking about ways to create the effect of crumbled paper for my website. The background color can vary, so the idea I came up with is to super impose the 'crumble' effect onto any colored background. Where can I find such a graphic? Any suggestions on how to make one if none are available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Scan or license a copy of an image of crumpled white paper
2. In your graphics editing software, copy *only* the shadows of black from the image (in Photoshop I use the *Select > Color Range* feature with the darkest shade selected and medium fuzziness)
3. Apply a threshold to the selection to ensure that only dark colors will be copied
4. Paste the shades of black onto a transparent canvas and save as PNG-24 with transparency

Examples:

[image: Color examples]

[image: PNG example]

Comment: exactly what i was looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean crumpled, rather than crumbled? As in screwed up and unfolded again, with lots of creases?

You will probably want an illustration without a semi-transparent background. The closest I could find was a folded piece of paper:
http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-illustration-5770021-folded-paper-background.php?st=3d670de